# Change the url and reload on change of dropdown value which is in common header

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii, yii-components

I am new to yii and I want to change url and reload the current view page on change of a dropdown value which is in the admin's common header field. 
Dropdown is


`echo $form->dropDownList($siteid, 'selectedsiteid', $data,$htmlOptions, array('class' => "form-control"));`

The current urls may be like the following

`1. http://localhost/zyntegra_commoditylifev2/admin/sitetag/viewTags/sid/6

 2.  http://localhost/zyntegra_commoditylifev2/admin/category/viewCategory/sid/ 
3.http://localhost/zyntegra_commoditylifev2/admin/site/index`
 Suppose the current changed dropdown value is `10` and If the current url is like (1) one then I need to change the url like this
 `http://localhost/zyntegra_commoditylifev2/admin/sitetag/viewTags/sid/10` 
 If the current url is like (2) one then 
 `http://localhost/zyntegra_commoditylifev2/admin/category/viewCategory/sid/10`
 and if it's like the (3) one then there is no need of reload.

Plz somebody help me to solve this problem.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Do you need it through php? or javascript will be ok?

Comment: javascript is ok. I think it can't do only by using php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like,

```
var tagsUrl='http://localhost/zyntegra_commoditylifev2/admin/sitetag/viewTags/sid/';
var catUrl='http://localhost/zyntegra_commoditylifev2/admin/category/viewCategory/sid/';
$(function(){
    $('#your-select-id').on('change',function(){
       href=window.location.href;
       if(href.indexOf('viewTags') !== -1){
           window.location.href=tagsUrl+this.value;//append value of select element
       } else if(href.indexOf('viewCategory') !== -1){
           window.location.href=catUrl+this.value;//append value of select element
       }
    });
});
```

Above code may help you to complete your task.

**Updated,** to get only sid then try it like,

```
// use location.href in url to get current url
var url='http://localhost/zyntegra_commoditylifev2/admin/sitetag/viewTags/sid/110';
alert(url.split('sid/')[1]);//110
```

**Updating** @salini answer like,

```
function reloadpage() {             
    var sid = $( '#Site_selectedsiteid' ).val( );
    var currentURL = window.location.pathname;
    var n=currentURL.indexOf("/sid");// use '/sid' only in indexOf to remove else part
    if(n!=-1) {
        var newurl = currentURL.substring(0,n); 
        window.location.href = newurl + '/sid/' + sid;
    }
}
```

Comment: but there is more urls like this i just mentioned only some of these

Comment: @Salini did you try above solution? what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: @kumar there are more like urls http://localhost/zyntegra_commoditylifev2/admin/sitetag/tags/sid ect ect

Comment: @Salini but, urls are same but parameter only different. Right?

Comment: I need if the last part of the url is like /sid/ or /sid/2(some value) then need to change it to /sid/10(current dropdown value)

Comment: @Salini ok then did you try above solution? Rohan solution will work for two urls. Do you have more than 2 urls?

Comment: ya Rohan's answer is current but i need to it with more urls

Comment: @Salini you can create an array of all urls and use it

Comment: @Rohan Now only i tried ur code but its not working no response and other links are also not working

Comment: @Rohan I want to check whether there any substring matching to /sid/ in the current url and if any substring matches then i want to get the proceeding substring (means if url is ..../sid/110 then I want to pick that 110 to a variable X then I want to check whether its null or any value. If it has a value then remove that number from url and replace it with current value. please help me to solve this

Comment: @Salini you can use `split()`, see my updated answer

Comment: @RohanKumar Thank u Rohan thats nice answer. Why I didnt thought /sid instide of /sid/  :-(

Comment: WC, don't know about your thinking. :)

Answer (score 1):

Ya I have Solved it. Here is my iavascript code

```
function reloadpage() {
     var sid = $('#Site_selectedsiteid').val();
     var currentURL = window.location.pathname;
     var n = currentURL.indexOf("/sid/");
     if (n != -1) {
         var newurl = currentURL.substring(0, n);
         window.location.href = newurl + '/sid/' + sid;
     } else {
         var n = currentURL.indexOf("/sid");
         if (n != -1) {
             var newurl = currentURL.substring(0, n);
             window.location.href = newurl + '/sid/' + sid;
         }
     }
}
```

It works properly. Thanks @Roshan and @kumar for ur kind help

Comment: I updated my answer again after looking your answer try it once.